# Stored procedure

Tags: java, mysql, sql, stored-procedures, jdbc

```
  String path= "Translator.txt";
       String file=" LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" + path +
                            "' INTO TABLE Translator " +
                            " FIELDS TERMINATED BY \',\' ENCLOSED BY \'\"'" +
                            " LINES TERMINATED BY \'\\n\'";
```

Is the following code above, a stored procedure?

Comment: no , this is not a SP . The SP starts with CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION/PROCEDURE

Comment: no this is only the string value concatenation. and add it in variable path and file

Comment: No, this is a regular statement.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Should a stored procedure run a query?

Comment: It is all your choice, but the whole point of creating an SP is I believe putting CRUD statements under one hood , which can be called by just calling that SP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store procedure is like which inputs some values and return data back , Or some insert , update , delete operations done by it. So yes there will be a query for store procedure.

This is a simple string statement.